# Xml Element to java Object which has package names

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am utilizing the external xml , In that xml element has package name, I am not sure how to map it to java object, Below is the picture of Xml Element

[image]

Comment: Maybe `class A {  @XmlElement(name = "com.blah.blah.Name") private SomeObject obj; }` where com.blah.blah.Name is your xml element's name (package etc.) and `SomeObject` is java class with all those fields like `name, caption, phi` , etc.

Comment: You could also try to create a class with `@XmlRootElement` and define your package.className stuff as the attribute to that annotation.

Comment: @john Tried that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i used these 2 classes & they worked like a champ.  this works with the top 3 elements, string, edu.common.blahblahblah, and it's nested element string. you'll have to add the rest in for yourself. in the future it would be much more helpful if you pasted text in versus an image capture. thx.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
public class Entry {

    private String string;  
    private MultiSelectListBox multiSelect;

    public Entry() { }

    /**
    * @return the string
    */
    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    /**
    * @param string the string to set
    */
    @XmlElement(name="string")
    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    /**
    * @return the multiSelect
    */
    public MultiSelectListBox getMultiSelect() {
        return multiSelect;
    }

    /**
    * @param multiSelect the multiSelect to set
    */
    @XmlElement(name = "edu.common.dynamicetextensions.domain.nui.MultiSelectListBox")
    public void setMultiSelect(MultiSelectListBox multiSelect) {
        this.multiSelect = multiSelect;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MultiSelectListBox {

    private int idNummer;
    private int responseID;


    public int getId() {
        return responseID;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.responseID = id;
    }

    private int getIdNummer() {
        return idNummer;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private void setIdNummer(int idNummer) {
        this.idNummer = idNummer;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works only if entry has multiselect let's say next entry has <entry><string></string><numberField></numberField></entry>, here in this we just have number Field and doesn't have multiselect anymore , then we will have this issue, not matter I just annotations on Fields and not on setters, I will try to do it on setters and see if it works, FYI this numberfield doesn't have package name assossiated with it

Comment: you're supposed to do it on the setters when you're demarshalling something. i used this post with Postman & it worked:

<entry>
 <string>outcomeMulit74903</string>
 <edu.common.dynamicetextensions.domain.nui.MultiSelectListBox id="957">
  <id>16</id>
 </edu.common.dynamicetextensions.domain.nui.MultiSelectListBox>
</entry>

Comment: I will try again @dienard, Do you think it has something to do with JAXB

Comment: nope. i don't have any problem with JaxB. what is this numberField you speak of? I did a generic example for you. now it's up to you to fit it to the package structure you need, etc. i'm not going to do it all for you.